# How to get the stack trace of all threads of a java application running on a remote windows machine

Tags: java, windows, command-line, stack-trace

I have a remote windows machine running some java cmd applications. I need to get the stack trace of the threads of the application from the command prompt of the local machine. Iam not supposed to use any thirdparty applications. Both the remote and the local machines have JDK 7 installed. What all details i have is

- remote machine name/IP address
- pid of the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** - You could start your applications with jmx options as below and connect to the jvm instance running on the remote machine through [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/). JVisualVM provides a way to take [thread dumps](http://visualvm.java.net/images/docs/thread-timeline-screen.png).

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

The thread dumps can saved to a text file (manually) for later analysis.

**Option 2** - If you want to automate the process of taking thread dumps, it would be simpler to add that logic in the java application itself. JMX provides a way to take thread dumps, though its format is different from what jstack (native) has

```
List<ThreadInfo> threads = Arrays.asList(ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().dumpAllThreads(true, true));
```

The `toString()` method of `ThreadInfo` does provide a readable version of the thread state including its stacktrace. You would have to customize it a bit to make it in parse-able by tools like [TDA](https://java.net/projects/tda)

**Option 3** - 
As you mention that you cannot tweak the running application, another option would be to execute a remote process using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx). Since its a windows server this should help. Have a look at the command line options [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

```
PsExec.exe \\RemoteMachine -u Domain\username -p password C:\java\jdk\bin\jstack.exe 7300 > E:\Dump\threaddump.txt
```

The threaddump.txt file should be created on the local machine. This could be then executed in a batch file to automate taking thread dumps periodically as shown below

```
:loop
&:: Add your remote psexec command here.
ping localhost -n 11 > nul
goto loop
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy for the answer. i want to get the thread stack trace details in a file, like what **jstack** is doing. So i think jvisualvm doesn't help me, since it is possible only to save it manually. I need an option like ** command >>file.txt **

Comment: I cannot do any tweaks in the java application( It's a production environment). i am running a monitoring application from my machine that has adequate privileges in the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

Since "no thirdparty applications, only jdk", then you should try **JConsole**, it's part of JDK, displays all kinds of infomation of java applications which should meet your need.

See here: [Exposing a Resource for Remote Management By JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/jconsole.html)

Generally, what you should do:

First, Start your java application on the remote machine with properties that expose the application for remote management, e.g.

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port = 9999  \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate = false \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl = false \
     YOUR_APP
```

Then, Start jconsole on the local machine, connect to the remote process exposed above by the format "HOSTNAME:PORT". After connected, just check out what you need in the tab "Thread".

Comment: Thanks @reniaL for the answer. i need to get the stack trace in a file. i need to parse the details later for some other uses. A GUI will no serve my purpose.